# AWS API Gateway: Log Query String in Access Log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've enabled Access Logging to CloudWatch for my API in AWS API Gateway and that works fine.
However, it will only log the path section of the URL and not my query string parameters.

My log format looks like this:

```
[$context.requestTime] ($context.status) "$context.httpMethod $context.path $context.requestId
```

Let's say, I call my API like this:

```
GET http://my.server.com/details?id=123
```

The corresponding access log line will look like this:

```
[19/Jun/2018:06:09:27 +0000] (200) "GET /details 5229a43c-7387-11e8-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

I need the id=123 as well, but I can't figure out how to access it. The documentation suggest using `$input.params('id')`, but that will always return `-`.

Comment: Does $input.params() return anything in your case?

Comment: Same, `$input.params()` also returns `-`. I tried all variations of it that I found.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke in console or with aws cli? There were some issues with params if you run it from console.

Comment: I'm setting this in the AWS Console. It's saving correctly, no error messages.

Comment: it seems there is no support for $input variables for custom access logging. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=860814&tstart=0

Comment: @MrTweek Are you still facing this issue? I can see query strings and their values in cloudwatch logs.

Comment: Came across this exact same issue today. Of course we want to be able to include the query string in the log! I am flabbergasted that there is no way of doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Only $context variables are supported, not $input, etc.
AWS Ref: Have you seen https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to figure out a way to log the query string other than to integrate it within my Lambda Authorizer. This is a code snippet. You then reference the query string in the access log format definition as "queryString": "$context.authorizer.queryString"

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    queryStringParameters = event["queryStringParameters"]
    queryString = urlencode(queryStringParameters)
    authResponse = {
        "principalId": "",
        "policyDocument": {
            "Version": "",
            "Statement": []
        }
    }
    
    authResponse["principalId"] = "user|a1b2c3d4"
    authResponse["policyDocument"]["Version"] = "2012-10-17"
    authResponse["policyDocument"]["Statement"] = []
    statementOne = {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": effect,
        "Resource": methodArn
    }
    authResponse["policyDocument"]["Statement"].append(statementOne)
    context = {
        'queryString': queryString
    }
    authResponse['context'] = context
    return authResponse
```

Comment: That's unusable, because authorizer response is cached. I.e. you will get old queryString.